# How to correctly configure Heroku Custom Domain

Tags: heroku, dns

When setting up my DNS `my.domain.com` (provided by GoDaddy) I am not sent to the correct address of my app, and the address in the URL bar is not what I expect either.

I have followed again and again the instructions outlined here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#summary-of-steps

I have tried adding a record of type `CNAME` with host as `www` and the target URL as `example-26hans7.herokudns.com`

Two expectations are not met:

1. When I navigate to my.domain.com I am not brought to the app which I added a domain to in the Heroku CLI (`my-app.herokuapp.com`), but instead to an empty app page (`example-26hans7.herokudns.com`). The result is not the same if I navigate to `my-app.herokuapp.com` directly, then my app is loaded as expected.
2. The URL in the address bar I would like to be `my.domain.com`. At present it seems to be redirecting me and so the URL in the address bar becomes `example-26hans7.herokudns.com`. This is no good for production.

Any help in this matter greatly appreciated.

Comment: DNS propagation can take some time. It can take up to 24-48 hours.

Comment: This I understand but it is already redirecting, however it is redirecting to the DNS address rather than the app's address. Additionally I do not want a full redirect as the address bar should still say `my.domain.com` not `my.herokuapp.com`. Can you enlighten me?

Comment: Might be useful https://youtu.be/IKlJzvT5Tf4

Comment: I appreciate the effort but this video is out of date, as per the Heroku docs I should be pointing it to the `my-app.herokudns.com` not `my-app.herokuapp.com`, however when I do that I get a "No such app" page instead of the expected "Hello World!". Any ideas?

To clarify I expect that by targeting the DNS on Heroku's end I will be forwarded to my app, as I have setup the domain in my Heroku app settings, but instead I am taken directly to the Heroku DNS address and my app is not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out you need to follow two steps in order for this to work with GoDaddy:

1. Create the CNAME as defined in the Heroku docs here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains
2. Enable forwarding. This can be found in the bottom right of the DNS management page. I had thought that forwarding was a redirecting option but it seems this needs to be enabled.
3. OPTIONAL: here you can also setup the subdomain such as `example.com` for `www.example.com`